# What is the file of a cube?

Tags: vocabulary, mathematics

In [Wikipedia 3D-Chess](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-dimensional_chess), it is written:

> A rook moves through the six faces of a cube in any rank, file, or
>   column

I understand what is a column for a cube. I also deduce that a rank is somewhat a row. And I also deduce that a file is a diagonal, but what are such words? A file and a rank for a face of a cube. I didn't see any of this vocabulary in [square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square) or [cube](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cube). Are such deductions correct? Is this vocabulary often used in English to describe some cube's parts, if not more used than diagonal and row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, these terms are not in general use for a cube.

They are normal terms in discussing chess, but hardly ever used (with these meanings) anywhere else.

A *rank* is a row parallel with the ends of a chessboard; a *file* a row parallel with the sides of the chessboard. Evidently in the 3D version, the writer is using *column* for the third dimension of the cubical board.

Answer (score 1):

This is an adaptation of *chess* terminology, not geometric terminiology.  Such words are not generally used to describe faces of a cube.

The files are the lines of cubes running from you to your opponent (forward and back) a "file" is not a diagonal. In neither 3d nor regular chess can a rook move diagonally.

The ranks are the lines of cubes running from side to side (left and right)  Both these words are used in regular 2d chess.

The columns run up and down.  Normal chess doesn't have columns.

You can't use these terms like this except in chess, or similar games.

(Rank, it seems, can also be used for the square slices of a the 3d board, so in 3d chess there is some ambiguity on how this word is used.)